# PHPmailer code works great to send to non-google apps email addresses but fails for google apps address

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, google-apps

I am having a unique issue (I did a thorough search on SO before I attempted to ask this question.
When I use the PHPMailer to send to a gmail (or hotmail, etc) address, it works great. As soon as I change it to send to a Google Apps email address, I don't get any error message instead it tells me it was successfull but no emails come through.

Has anybody seen this issue before? Is my code missing something very particular that makes it a valid email to pass through Google Apps Servers (not sure if I am heading in the right direction here). Thank you!

Start of my Code:

```
<?php

require("/PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->Mailer = 'mail';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "******@dynamicsafetyfirst.com";
$mail->Password = "*******";

$mail->From     = $_POST['email'];
$mail->AddAddress("someuser@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
$mail->Subject = $_POST['enquiry'];
$mail->Body = $_POST['comments']. "--By--".' name: '. $_POST['name']."--". 'email: ' .$_POST['email']; 

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

END OF CODE.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting in quite a lot of effort to do things wrong. First up you're using a pretty old version of PHPMailer - go get the latest [from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Next, your code has many issues, so start again using the [gmail example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). Use tls on port 587. Do not set `Mailer` - you've already called `isSMTP()`, and overriding `Mailer` later is asking for trouble.

To see what is going on set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`, and it will show you the whole SMTP conversation. At that point you may get some clue as to what is happening to your message.